# Chess self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: Anna, in the past 2 weeks or so the site became much quieter than it had been (in terms of activity at least, as site visits are still about where they were), quite abruptly. So I think this will ultimately yield much less feedback than it might have just a short while ago (though I know that fact itself is a sort of feedback).

Answer (score 7):

[Do strong players move their pieces with different relative frequencies than weak players?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/982/do-strong-players-move-their-pieces-with-different-relative-frequencies-than-wea)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 6):

[Should I recapture the queen with my king or knight in the Scotch Game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/963/should-i-recapture-the-queen-with-my-king-or-knight-in-the-scotch-game)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 3):

[How should white continue after 5...Qf6 in the Scotch Game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/997/how-should-white-continue-after-5-qf6-in-the-scotch-game)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 3):

[Piece movement statistics](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/979/piece-movement-statistics)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 2):

[Why did Viktor Korchnoi leave the USSR?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/993/why-did-viktor-korchnoi-leave-the-ussr)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 2):

[Are there statistics on the frequency of tactical motifs?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/989/are-there-statistics-on-the-frequency-of-tactical-motifs)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[Joining a league or tournament](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/984/joining-a-league-or-tournament)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[Rivals to the FIDE](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/974/rivals-to-the-fide)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[Prophylactic defenses](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/977/prophylactic-defenses)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[How is chess viewed in USSR vs Post-USSR?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/999/how-is-chess-viewed-in-ussr-vs-post-ussr)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I don't think this post is inherently bad, but as it played out, it resulted in a discussion that was more politics than chess. To be clear, I think that there is some room for talk of _chess politics_ on the site, but here we basically ended up in plain old politics absent any substantial relation to chess.